# How to merge the two table columns into one table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the two tables with each having 4 columns and 4 rows. I need the result of 1 table having 8 columns and 8 rows.

Screenshots of table attached:

[image: Table Picture]

Comment: Amm... you forgot the screenshots

Comment: @Mureinik they are in the source. It requires a minimum rep to post images.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh, edited to include them

Comment: Sorry guys. Its my first question here. Added the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
       FULL OUTER JOIN table2 
                    ON 1 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, it worked like a charm. I was trying CROSS JOIN but was not getting the nulls. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union all` operator and explicitly add the `null`s:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, NULL AS a1, NULL AS b1, NULL AS c1, NULL AS d1
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, a1, b1, c1, d1
FROM   table2
```